# How do I animate a UIButton between two PNG images?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, uibutton

I have two PNGs I want to use as a button. How can I animate a UIButton by switching rapidly between these two images?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `animationImages` property of your button's `imageView`:

```
myButton.imageView.animationImages =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                          nil];
myButton.imageView.animationDuration = 0.5; //whatever you want (in seconds)
[myButton.imageView startAnimating];
```

Your button will switch between your two images.

**EDIT:** As @tidbeck pointed the button needs to have an image assigned to create the `imageview`  property.

Comment: For some reason I just get a blank space where the button should be. Is this still possible in iOS5?

Comment: According to (Apple's docs)[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html] yes.

Comment: I needed to set an image on the button first `[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];` for the `ImageView` to be created.

Comment: Why not use a animated image directly, if your images have the same prefix, you can use this `[myButton setImage:[UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"image" duration:0.5] forState:UIControlStateNormal]`. In Swift `myButton.setImage(UIImage.animatedImageNamed("image", duration: 0.5), forState: .Normal)`

Answer (score 1):

Normally for a button you can set three "live" states:
- Normal
- Highlighted
- Selected
I don't know if this can help, but if you set one image to "Normal" and the other image to "Highlighted" you can see the two images while pushing the button.
I don't know if this effect is enough for you.

Comment: I wanted the button to animate on it's own, without user input. I've looked at a hundred articles, all I see, though, are how to translate, rotate, etc., just manipulating existing images, not animating with new ones.

Answer (score 0):

This small example shows how to set a UIButton to show an indefinite animation of a heart beating.

I have added 8 images into the Assets.xcassets, and named them like this: `heart1`, `heart2`, ..., `heart8`.

```
private func showHeartedAnimation() {
    var images = [UIImage]()
    for i in 1...8 { images.append(UIImage(named: "heart\(i)")!) }
    self.heartButton.setImage(UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: 0.2), for: .normal)
}
```

If you want to disable the animation at some point, just assign a simple UIImage to the same button.