# Animation on button using images

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have a UIButton which has arrow kind of blue image set as

```
     UIImage *arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bluearrow.png"];
    [self.prevbutton setBackgroundImage:arrowImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now I have another image yellow.png, that I want to super impose on top of this button image and make a flashing animation continuously. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This should help you.

```
myButton.imageView.animationImages =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                          nil];
myButton.imageView.animationDuration = 0.5; //whatever you want (in seconds)
[myButton.imageView startAnimating];
```

As quoted from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490535/716216

Comment: I recently needed to animate a button between a pair of images, and wasn't sure how altering the image in the button's imageView property would interact with the setImage:forState method. Does activating an image view animations array on the button's image view override the image set with setImage:forState? (What I ended up doing is adding a second image for the selected state, and then running a repeating timer that toggles the button state back and forth between selected and !selected. That works beautifully, but would not work if you wanted more than 2 animation images.)

Comment: @DuncanC That's a really good question, I guess how this would be set up would depend on how you would want the button the behave when selected. I'll have to try this again and see wether or not the buttons image changes away from the animation when in its selected state. Good work around though!