# Exit from void method if action done

Tags: ios, objective-c, void

In my program I used a `void` method and I want to stop this when the button action is done.

in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self runningaction];
```

and out side of the viewDidLoad

```
-(void)runningaction
{
    some code 
}
```

another method for `UIButton` action

```
-(void)clicktosee
{
    //here  i need to write code for stop the -(void)runningaction
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you do in running action ? - Do you start a task on another thread or dispatch queue? `viewDidLoad` is only called once when the view is loaded and so `runningAction` will only get called once

Comment: in running action isto display 2 background images for buttons . it'll be like that ever.
i need to change button backgroundimgae when the clicktosee is done. got it

Comment: So you are starting an animation in `-(void)runningaction`? Remember that if you put a `while(1) { //something }` (or similar) there, the function will never end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put check that method is implemented then just return that's what i tried

```
-(void)clicktosee
{
  if( [self respondsToSelector:@selector(runningaction)] ) {
        return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understood your question (and comment) correctly, you want to start some animations on button images, and then stop them on user action.

This can be achieved like this :

```
-(void)runningaction {
    myButton.imageView.animationImages =
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                      nil];
    myButton.imageView.animationDuration = 0.5; //whatever you want (in seconds)
    myButton.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; //0 means repeat forever here
    [myButton.imageView startAnimating];
 }
```

Then in `-(void)clicktosee` you simple write this line : `[myButton.imageView stopAnimating]`.

Hope I understood you correctly.

**NOTE :** The animation code is taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490535/765298) by @ender.

Comment: i am not doing any animations i just need to write for changing the background image. can i use this for it.

Comment: Yes - consider what an animation is : it is (in its simplest) a sequence of changing images. Above code will alternate a background image of a button every half second between two images. You can of course supply more images, change the time, etc.

Comment: Could you be more specific?